# Concatenate 2 fields

Tags: python, odoo

here is my function

```
def get_concat(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
  x = {}
  for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids ,context):
       x[record.id] = record.a+"--"+ record.b
  return x
```

Definition of the fields

```
   'a' : fields.integer('A'),
   'b' : fields.integer('B'),
   'concat' : fields.function(get_concat, method=True, string='Inventaires',type='char', size=40),
```

my tree view does'nt display any record. when I comment the function field, all is fine. That's how I knew that my function is not correct
can you tell me what's error i made in this function!
Thank you

Comment: You need to try to narrow the problem, can you print out record.a, record.b, record.id and show us what you get?

Comment: I guess you are doing something with OpenERP. Could you provide a little more context for your code?

Comment: can you paste the field you have defined??

Comment: "does not work" -> please tell us how it does not work (traceback...). Providing the field definition of record.a and record.b would also be very helpful.

Comment: I don"t get any error! just my tree view does'nt display any record. when I comment the function field, all is fine. That's how I knew that my function is not correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as field a and field b both are integer .
int and str concatenation is not possible in python without type casting.

so either you have defined datatype of a,b wrongly(use char as datatype) or use

$ x[record.id] = str(record.a or '') + "--" + str(record.b or '')

Comment: I try to change the type of a and b by char but this didn't solve the issue.So I just put :x[record.id] = str(record.a) + "--" + str(record.b);Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you tell the traceback info i can help you.

But BTW in python if you want concatenate in a secure way and avoid unespected traceback i change your line.

x[record.id] = record.a+"--"+ record.b

By

x[record.id] = "%s--%s" % ( str(record.a), str(record.b))

Comment: `str()` isn't necessary when using `%s`.

Comment: I don"t get any error! just my tree view does'nt display any record. when I comment the function field, all is fine. That's how I knew that my function is not correct!

Answer (score 1):

At first site your function looks like OK.

But Error can occur in case of when record.a or reocrd.b value is "False"

**it will try to concat False to String.**

so in that case you have to first check the condition before concating the variables.